# Font looks not clear on different websites

Tags: windows-10, browser, fonts

I have tried different browsers and changed various settings on my windows 10 but cannot figure out the solution. It also happens on other websites like geeksforgeeks.I have to zoom in to get the clear text but it's not a solution. Any solutions to this problem??

[image]